# Making sense of D3 code

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to implement something similar to **[this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292)**, so I am trying to understand this code.

There are certain things which I am having a tough time to understand. For instance, in the code below, `path.attr("d", linkArc);` seems to be calling the `linkArc` function. However, `linkArc` function expects a parameter, which is not passed. Still it manages to get an Object called `d`. What object is this and how is it getting passed? What does `d` in `path.attr` signify?

```js
// Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
function tick() {
    path.attr("d", linkArc); //<- this line
    circle.attr("transform", transform);
    text.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {
  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}
```

Can someone please help me understand this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [d3 docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections):

> ## selection.attr(name[, value])
>
> ...if value is a function, then the function is evaluated for each
>   selected element (in order), being passed the current datum `d` and the
>   current index `i`, with the this context as the current DOM element. The
>   function's return value is then used to set each element's attribute.
>   A null value will remove the specified attribute...

That's where the `d` is coming from. It's the `selection` Objects currently set `d` (datum).

A nice illustration of this in action is if you also add `i` to the `linkArc()` function:

```
function linkArc(d,i) {
    console.log('d: ' + d + ' || i: ' + i);
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}
```

And a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wahwahwah/Qh9X5/4766/)

Comment: Thank you, that really helped. Now here is the challenging part. I am trying to use this D3 code within Ext JS. When I do this in Ext JS [code]tick: function(path)  {
   console.log('Inside Tick --');
   path.attr("d", linkArc);
   circle.attr("transform", transform);
   text.attr("transform", transform);
 },

 linkArc: function(d) {
   var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
    dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
    dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
   return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
 } [code] I get error linkArc not defined

Comment: Is there a better way to post a follow up question? Asking it using 'Add Comment' doesn't seem to be the right thing to do as there is no option to format the code. Sorry was being so naive

Comment: I would think the best way to go about it is to post a new question specific to Ext JS and D3 and then link back to this post for reference. Normally, if your asking for clarification you can just update your original post - but this  seems like it belongs in a new thread

Answer (score 3):

This is how the .attr() operator works:

Quote from the d3 documentation (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#attr):

> ## selection.attr(name[, value])
>
> If value is specified, sets the attribute with the specified name to
>   the specified value on all selected elements. If value is a constant,
>   then all elements are given the same attribute value; otherwise, **if
>   value is a function, then the function is evaluated for each selected
>   element (in order), being passed the current datum d and the current
>   index i, with the this context as the current DOM element**. The
>   function's return value is then used to set each element's attribute.
>   A null value will remove the specified attribute.

Basically it means you can use the function like this:

```
function linkArc(d, i) {
  // 'd' is the datum
  // 'i' is the index
  // 'this' will be the current DOM element
}
```

Comment: Almost exactly the same answer - posted at the same time. :)